# getmxrr and Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference

Tags: php, error-handling

PHP Documentation for [getmxrr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmxrr.php) specifies the syntax as

```
bool getmxrr ( string $hostname , array &$mxhosts [, array &$weight ] )
```

This function is not depreciated (not replaced by a more favored one). However, when using the function as described, I get this warning:

> Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated  in
> path/to/script on line n

So, how should this utility be used without causing PHP to complain?

*And isn't it absurd the language frowns at its own prescription?*

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: @Pekka - Like this `$check = @getmxrr ( $domain, &$mxhosts, &$weight );`, and even the error suppression does not silence the warning!

Comment: You need to share your code to answer your question. You made a slight error, and it's like you need to remove some `&` character to have this work, but as you have not shared your code it can't finger-pointed on that character.

Comment: @hakre - You are right, thanks. I added the line causing the warning in my answer to Pekka. I will add it to the body of my question too.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour: Please read about the conventions in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php (See the first **Note** box)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you should call it; the function declares the reference, it's not meant to be used at call time.

```
$mxhosts = $weight = array(); // not really necessary but good for form :)
$res = getmxrr('example.com', $mxhosts, $weight);
// $mxhosts and $weight are populated
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Thanks! But why does the documentation say the two arrays should be passed in by reference?

Comment: @Majid they are implicitly passed by reference because of the `&` in the function declaration. There's no need to do that when calling it

Comment: @MajidFouladpour the documentation shows the function declaration, not how it's called :) The link I added shows examples of this; adding the reference sign inside the function declaration is now the only right way of doing pass-by-reference.